# Only load jQuery script if cookies aren't present

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I'm curious. I have a bit of a fade out div working on a site I'm building. You visit the site, a div is present which has the title of the site in it, then after a period it fades out. Simple.

```
<div class="loader"><h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></h1></div>

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

What I'm after is that this div and the jQuery will only show/run if the user is visiting the site for the first time or has cleared their cache/cookies since last visit.

Any ideas? I'm sure cookies.js would've been useful but seems in-development now.

Cheers,
R

Comment: You could use `localStorage` as an alternative to cookies (html5 only though) - http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

Comment: There are several jquery cookie plguins out there where you can check for your cookie. I havn't ever relied on them because i wrote my own. If a premade out there doesnt suit you, I have mine available at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/9kuNv/), tho its not closure compiled and therefor kinda long atm, but you could always copy the plugin part (its between comments) comile it, file it, and add it to your site for very easy cookie manipulation nd checks. I cant compile it right now because my work doesnt allow access to compiler's online, lol.

Comment: why not just use `if (document.cookiename.value = '') {code}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) { ?>

      <div class="loader"><h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></h1></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
        $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut();
        });
      </script>

    <?php 
     setcookie ("visited", "", time() + 31536000,"/");
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kev - where/what should I be putting in $_COOKIE['name_of_cookie']?

Comment: I have edited the code - I assumed that the cookie was already being set - instead I have included a set cookie statement and check for the cookie by name